# Copy Selection Interior ColorIndex to same area on different Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I'm trying to copy the Colorindex of a highlighted selection to a different Worksheet.

I have 4 different Worksheets and on sheet 1 the user is able to colorize the Cells. Then I want him to be able to select an area of those cells an copy the colors to all other sheets (same location) by clicking a button that triggers my sub "Mark_all".

I'm stuck because "selection" seems to contain the Worksheet on which the selection has been made.

Here is what I tried:

```
Dim CurCell As Range
Dim ColCurCell As Integer
Dim cWs As Worksheet

Sub Mark_all()
For Each CurCell In Selection
ColCurCell = CurCell.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each cWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If cWs.Name <> "A Worksheet I DonT want to be changed" Then
    CurCell.Interior.ColorIndex = ColCurCell  '<-- Here I dont know how to combine my CurCell with the other Worksheets
    End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address):

```
For Each cWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If cWs.Name <> "A Worksheet I DonT want to be changed" Then
        cWs.Range(CurCell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = ColCurCell
    End If
Next
```